# How do I make the images to appear and change with a 'click'?

Tags: javascript, dom

https://github.com/baolmovement/wdi-fundamentals-memorygame

Above is the repo for my project. I'm trying to A) get card images to appear B)have the card images flip to the face image.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var flipCard = function(){ 

var cardId = this.getAttribute('data-id');

var cardOne = cards[0];
cardsInPlay.push(cards[0].rank);
console.log("User flipped " + cards[0].rank);  
console.log(cards[0].cardImage);



var cardTwo = cards[2];
cardsInPlay.push(cards[2].rank);
console.log("User flipped " + cards[2].rank); 
console.log(cards[2].cardImage);

console.log (this.cardImage).setAttribute('src', this);

if (cardsInPlay.length === 2){alert("Sorry, try again!")} 
    else if (cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]) {alert("You found a match!");}   

checkForMatch;

};   

var createBoard = function(){ 
for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {   
    var cardElement = document.createElement('img');  
    cardElement.setAttribute('src', "images/back.png"); 
    cardElement.setAttribute(i,'data-id'); 
    cardElement.addEventListener('click',flipCard);   
    cardElement.appendChild('game-board')
};

createdBoard();
```

Comment: Post the relevant code in your question, not on an external site.

Comment: Just made the changes. 'game-board' is the div id in the HTML. Sorry I'm a newb if you couldn't tell.

Comment: There are too many incorrect usage of JavaScript. I suggest you go through your code first and understand what you are coding.